# Pointer to function from a member's function

Tags: c++, scope, function-pointers

I have a bit complex situation. It may can easily be solved by inheritance, but I am now curious and due some other reasons I would solve it this way.

I have class which represents an algorithm and with time a different solution has been implemented. Currently, I have the original class, and it's member is the new one.
I would have both of the algorithm and a switch to be able to use them according to the situation.

```
#include "B.h"
class A {
public:
    typedef void ( A::*FooFunction )( float, float );
    A::FooFunction m_fooFunction;
    B m_b;

    A( WhichUseEnum algorithm ) : m_b( B() )
    {
        switch( algorithm ) {
        case ALG_A:
            m_fooFunction = &A::FooFunctionOfA;
            break;
        case ALG_B:
            m_fooFunction = ??? // something like: m_b.FooFunctionOfA
            break;
        }
    }

    void FooFunction( float a , float b)
    {
         ( this->*m_fooFunction )( a, b );
    }

    void FooFunctionOfA( float, float ); // implementation at the .cpp
};

class B {
public:
    void FooFunctionOfB( float, float );
}
```

As you can see, I want to save the pointer to function of the member m_b and call it as the FooFunction does. With the own function ( FooFunctionOfA() ) I was already successful, but the other is much harder. I tried several idea, but I could not find the version which was accepted by the compiler. :)

I found a similar question where the solution looked like this: `&m_b.*m_b.FooFunctionOfB` and at this point I gave it up.

If anybody has some idea, pleas do not hesitate to share with me.

I am using C++ but not C++0x AND I am forced to avoid stl and boost.

Comment: The problem is that the `FooFunction` type is a pointer to a member function in the class `A`, and `A` and `B` are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a wrapper function that does the job.

```
#include "B.h"
class A {
public:
    typedef void ( A::*FooFunction )( float, float );
    A::FooFunction m_fooFunction;
    B m_b;

    A( WhichUseEnum algorithm ) : m_b( B() )
    {
        switch( algorithm ) {
        case ALG_A:
            m_fooFunction = &A::FooFunctionOfA;
            break;
        case ALG_B:
            m_fooFunction = &A::FooFunctionOfB;
            break;
        }
    }

    void FooFunction( float a , float b)
    {
         ( this->*m_fooFunction )( a, b );
    }

    void FooFunctionOfA( float, float ); // implementation at the .cpp

    // A wrapper function that redirects the call to B::fooFunctionOfB().  
    void FooFunctionOfB( float a, float b)
    {
       this->m_b.FooFunctionOfB(a, b);
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void FooFunctionOfB( float, float );
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether to downvote or not. Unlike the other answer this does actually solve his problem and it's not a disgusting hideous mess. But you really should be recommending std::function here.

Comment: Should, but in my case this seems the "cleanest" solution". I did not mentioned, but I am forced to avoid stl.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `std::tr1::function`. This class is built for the purpose you need. It can accept any function, member function, etc.

```
class A {
public:
    std::tr1::function<void(float, float)> m_fooFunction;
    B m_b;

    A( WhichUseEnum algorithm ) : m_b( B() )
    {
        switch( algorithm ) {
        case ALG_A:
            m_fooFunction = std::tr1::bind(&A::FooFunctionOfA, this);
            break;
        case ALG_B:
            m_fooFunction = std::tr1::bind(&A::FooFunctionOfA, &m_b);
            break;
        }
    }

    void FooFunction( float a , float b)
    {
         m_fooFunction( a, b );
    }

    void FooFunctionOfA( float, float ); // implementation at the .cpp
};

class B {
public:
    void FooFunctionOfB( float, float );
}
```

Here I have used `std::tr1::bind` to define the two functions. As you can see the calling syntax is much easier too- just like a regular function call. `std::tr1::bind` can bind a lot more than just member functions and member function pointers too. Gah, it's been a while since I had to use `bind` instead of lambdas.

The general rule of C++ is that if you're using function pointers or member function pointers and you're not interfacing to some old code then you're almost certainly doing it wrong. This is no exception. If you're pre-C++0x then you may need to `bind` them too but that's about it.

If you're using a compiler so old, *it doesn't even have TR1*, you can use Boost to substitute these facilities- they were Standardised from Boost so the Boost equivalent is very close in functionality and interface.

Comment: You have absolutely right, this is the real solution when the usage of stl is allowed. I am bit confused now, which answer should be accepted?

Comment: Your question does not actually state that you cannot use the Standard library or Boost, so you can either edit it and accept the other guy's or accept this one.

Answer (score -2):

What you should have done:

(1) Extract Interface on the original algorithm. Now the original algorithm is an implementation of this virtual interface.

```
class FooFunctionInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Foo(float a, float b) = 0;
};

class OriginalFoo : public FooFunctionInterface
{
public:
    void Foo(float a, float b) override
    {
       /* ... original implementation ... */
    }
};
```

(2) Introduce the new algorithm as an alternate implementation of the interface.

```
class NewFoo : public FooFunctionInterface
{
public:
    void Foo(float a, float b) override
    {
      /* ... new implementation ... */
    }
};
```

(3) Introduce a factory function for selecting which implementation to use.

```
class NullFoo : FooFunctionInterface
{
public:
    void Foo(float a, float b) override {}
};

std::unique_ptr<FooFunctionInterface> FooFactory(WhichUseEnum which)
{
    std::unique_ptr<FooFunctionInterface> algorithm(new NullFoo());

    switch(which)
    {
    case ALG_A: algorithm.reset(new OriginalFoo()); break;
    case ALG_B: algorithm.reset(new NewFoo()); break;
    };

    return algorithm;
}
```

Then your class A becomes pimpl idiom forwarding calls to the appropriate implementation.

```
class A
{
public:
      A(WhichUseEnum which) 
          : pimpl_(FooFactory(which))
      {
      }

      void Foo(float a, float b)
      {
         pimpl_->Foo(a, b);
      }

private:
      std::unique_ptr<FooFunctionInterface> pimpl_;
};
```

Hugely cleaner approach to the mess you've made. You know its cleaner when you consider what will happen when you need to add the third implementation, then the fourth implementation.

In my example, you extend the factory function and move on with your life. No other code changes.

Comment: You mean, "Badly reimplement `std::function` and also introduce null object anti-pattern"? Nice move.

Comment: No, I mean use the strategy pattern.

Comment: Dude if you think null object pattern is an anti-pattern... wow.

Comment: That appears to be entirely equivalent to my sarcasm above. There's plenty of non-pattern "patterns" and I'll have to add Strategy to my mental list if this stuff is what you get by following it. You haven't followed any logic or reason or correctly re-used the parts provided by the Standard library, just splurged "ER MAH GERD PATTERNS" all over it.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth if the actual implementations of the algorithms are complicated you do it this way because the code is cleaner. 

When they're one liners this would be overkill.

Comment: This is "cleaner" than using the Standard pre-provided generic implementation? You need to wash your eyes, buddy.

Comment: :) I love std::function. I use it whenever I need to allow the user to register callbacks. As I said to ScarletAmaranth it really depends on the complexity of the Foo() function. Sure if they were a line or two, I'd do what you did. 

I didn't make that assumption, you apparently did. Fine.